# Simplest way to define ColorMap for depth_first_search

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I want to use the depth_first_search algorithm. Since I need
the DFS version where a start vertex is specified, I also 
have to define a ColorMap. That's the function I want to
use :

```
template <class Graph, class DFSVisitor, class ColorMap>
void depth_first_search(const Graph& g, DFSVisitor vis, ColorMap color, 
             typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor start)
```

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html

Since the map is irrelevant for me, the default `ColorMap` would be fully sufficient.
Could you give me a hint how to create and pass it as argument in depth_first_search it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the named parameter overload instead, which will let you specify a start vertex while just using the default color map.

```
template <class Graph, class class P, class T, class R>
void depth_first_search(Graph& G, const bgl_named_params<P, T, R>& params);
```

Example:

```
boost::depth_first_search(graph, boost::root_vertex(start_vertex));
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with 0x5453's answer. It's easier to use named parameters overload. But if you do want to know how to intialize a `ColorMap` object, here is the answer.

> Default: an iterator_property_map created from a std::vector of default_color_type of size num_vertices(g) and using the i_map for the index map.

```
Graph g;

/*
 * do something with graph
 */

// number of colors should be the same as number of vertices.
std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors(boost::num_vertices(g));

// create a ColorMap object (cpp_version < 17)
auto color_map = boost::make_iterator_property_map(colors.begin(),
    boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g));

// In C++17, make_iterator_property_map isn't necessary, as we have class 
// template argument deduction
boost::iterator_property_map color_map(colors.begin(),
    boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g));
```

Here [make_iterator_property_map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/property_map/doc/iterator_property_map.html) takes two arguments and returns an `iterator_property_map`. The first argument is the iterator over color values, and the second argument is the mapping between graph's vertex index and `colors` index.